# How do I render data from model.rb into the index.html file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

I'm building my first rails app and I have my HTML and CSS files set up in /public and models.rb in /models housing my code.

Right now the code is one Def that searches for the 5 most recent tweets mentioning me in the models.rb file.

I want to take those 5 tweets and style them in a certain way. I've never accessed data from one file to another so not quite sure how to get those tweets to appear in the index.html file.

Any help much appreciated.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

def search
  search = Twitter::Search.new
  search.containing("@twitter").result_type("recent").per_page(5).each do |r|
     puts "#{r.from_user}: #{r.text}"
  end
end

search #calls search function
```

That is the code in models.rb, need to get that to show in index.html

Comment: Show you code. It's difficult to help without more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to organize your files properly. You didn't mention controllers, but you'll need one for each type of 'thing' you want users to interact with. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

You want a file structure like this:

CSS in `/public/stylesheets/whatever.css`
HTML in `/app/views/tweets/index.html.erb`

Bear in mind I'm not familiar with your specific database structure, but in the `tweets` controller (stored in `/app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb`) you'd ideally want to be able to do this:

```
def index
    @tweets = @user.tweets.order("tweets.created_at DESC").limit(5)
end
```

Then in `index.html.erb`:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <div class="tweet">
        <%= @tweet.text %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the most detail I can give you from your question - you should read about the MVC structure in rails and most of all, take the time to get your project started/organized well. It'll save lots of headache for you in the future!

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the hassle

Comment: @ZackShapiro - no problem at all! We all start in the same place after all :)

Comment: We do. Unfortunately two people disagree with that apparently based on those downvotes

Comment: @ZackShapiro - SO is a very high quality forum, and it stays that way because of expectations and conventions that are not always obvious to those just starting out here. I personally believe that leniency is the way to go with beginners but others are more strict w.r.t those conventions. In any case, I hope this answer was helpful to you. Welcome to SO!